# Django-Blog comments form not appearing

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am currently following the Django-Blog tutorial on the Django-Central site and I am trying to add the comment section to the blog. I have got my comments displaying, but I cant seem to get the form to display so that site visitors can add comments to the blog posts.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post
from .forms import CommentForm


# Create your views here.
class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'


def post_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    # Fetching the comments that have active=True
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None

    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

        print('Comments:', comments)
        return render(request,
                      template_name,
                        {'post': post,
                        'comments': new_comment,
                        'new_comment': new_comment,
                        'comment_form': comment_form})
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Comment
from django import forms


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

post_detail.html

```
<div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- comments -->
                    <h2>{{ post.comments.count }} comments</h2>

                    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                    <div class="comments" style="padding: 10px;">
                        <p class="font-weight-bold">
                            {{ comment.name }}
                            <span class="">
                                {{ comment.created_on }}
                           </span>
                        </p>
                        {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    {% if new_comment %}
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        Your comment is awaiting moderation
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    <h3>Leave a comment</h3>
                    <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

You referenced the wrong template context, form doesn't exist, you should be using `comment_form`, that's what you called it in the `render` method.

Should be `{{ comment_form.as_p }}`.

Comment: I have tried doing it that way also but it still doesnt display. Thats why Im completly lost now.

Comment: I also see you have a error in your code `comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.PSOT)`, shoud be `POST`.

Comment: Also, I don't see how this page renders on first viewing, where's the code that handles GET request for this page?

Comment: Oh damn didnt see that. Well I changed it but still no luck unfortunately, but Im sure that fixed a future problem. Thanks for that

Comment: Which GET requests? I dont understand, Im quite new so I followed the Django-Blog tutorial on the Django-Central site. but that seems to be out of date or something because it doesnt seem to work anymore. Even trying to copy paste over to replace my code and jump back to see the differences, their code doesnt work either so Im not sure whats up

Comment: I meant, where's the view code for renderings this form for users on first viewing. (i.e. i view the page, I have not yet edited form/posted form data).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208277/discussion-between-blademaster680-and-user13653).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `URL` pattern in the app directory solved my issue, replace the:

```py
postDetail.as_view()
```

with:

```py
post_detail.["The issue is from loading the form and the `URL` pattern setup..."]
```

Comment: Please surround your code with backticks (`) to format it.